# Cannot have more then one folder in drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a big amount of images mostly used for animations. I find it hard to look at this unorganized mess because I can't put folders in res/drawable. If I do images don't show up. Why can't I make any folders in drawable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's something Google didn't think of and It's highly annoying.
There is even a post on this issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2018).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible because you can't have two images with the same name (in different folders). The R class wouldn't know which to pick up.

The only way to make it less annoying is to work on your image names adding prefixes so you know what they are used for.

Comment: I think It's not a biggie for Google to make Folders for drawable available.

Comment: @ismetkrlic: Android is an open source project. You are welcome to rewrite the development tools, and possibly the OS itself, to support this. Visit http://source.android.com for details of making contributions to the project. Or, if you lack the time to do it yourself, perhaps you could hire a development team to work on those improvements and contribute them to the project. After all, if it is "not a biggie", you will not mind doing the work yourself or paying for the work to be done, to benefit yourself and everyone else.